# Data.ForEach not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, for-loop

I'm trying to loop through data array and this works fine:

```
data.forEach((entry) => {
    if(entry[1]) {
        window.optionsAv = 1;
        window.optionsAmnt = window.optionsAmnt + 1;

        $('#timeswrap').show();
        $('#tijden').append("<option class='single-tijd' data-optieId='" + entry[3] + "'>" + entry[0] + "</option>");
    } else {
    }
})
```

But it doesn't seem to work in Internet Explorer. 
What would be a better solution?

Comment: What exactly is the error? What version of Internet Explorer are you talking about? There's a vast difference between IE8 and IE Edge for example.

Comment: which version of IE?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=foreach

Comment: It's probably the arrow function, which only works from Edge onward. forEach works from IE9+

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Thanks for responding! It gives an error about the data.foreach syntax. If a click on a checkbox it sends a post to return data with certain times. But this is obviously not working at all. and tested in internet explorer 11!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"=>" is only in ES6 and Msie don't support ES6.

http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html

Comment: Ah i see. i will change it to without =>. thank you!